# For loop with Set, is it O(n)?

Tags: java, big-o

I have this for loop:

```
public void method(int[] arr) {
    Set set = new HashSet();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        set.add(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

is this method in O(n)?

Comment: As far as I know HashSet is constant time when adding, in that case then yes it's O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a HashSet, **yes**.
`HashSet` has `O(1)` and you multiply it with `O(n)` by using a for-loop. Thus, the whole construct has `O(n)`.

Answer (score -1):

`HashSet` has a near-linear insertion performance, so yes: n such operations would be O(n).

Note that I would do this instead, which achieves exactly the same result as what all your code does:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

You shoukd type your Set too, as above.

Comment: But `Set`will have the size of one and I agree with typing the `Set.`

Comment: What do you mean? This code achieves exactly what your code does.

Comment: No, in my code, for [1,2,3] `set` has the size of 3. But your code the size is always one!

Comment: It's been so long since I used an untyprd list... You need to type it - you should anyway. See edited answer.

Comment: The code you've posted won't compile because `Arrays.asList` doesn't work usefully with arrays of primitives. (It will box the argument into an `int[][]` and return a `List<int[]>`, which will then be incompatible with the `HashSet<Integer>`).